# Keep getting signed out of Orchard

Tags: orchardcms

I have deployed Orchard to my online webserver. It's all working quite nicely, untill I log into the dashboard and try to create pages and such. I keep getting signed out, Orchard tells me access is denied. When I enter my credentials again, I log in and am able to view the page and continue. But after some clicking, I'm signed out again. Before getting signed out, there appears to be a long wait. What could cause this?

Update: I have the idea that it's a time out of some sort. Either on the cookie, or some process on the server taking a long time. Overall, the performance of the site on the server isn't that great. Pages take a long time (several seconds) to load. It's a shared hosting environment, so I don't have acccess to the server itself unfortunately. But as a comparison; I'm also running a Wordpress installation on the same box and that's just plain quick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First hypothesis: your shared host is too weak, and has strict memory restrictions that cause the application to restart all the time. Fix: find a decent ASP.NET hosting company. That their plan works with a PHP app such as WordPress is no good indication of the quality of their ASP.NET service.

Second hypothesis: you are missing a machine key: http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Setting-up-a-machine-key

Comment: Thanks. Setting up the machine key (which I hadn't done) made some difference, but doesn't make it real quick (like it is on my development machine). So I'm afraid you're right about the host being not too great (it's a cheap one, I admit). I'll contact them and if things don't get better, move to another one.